# Internet Explorer 8 EmulateIE7 Mode not working

Tags: internet-explorer, iis, iis-6, internet-explorer-8

I've set up IIS6 to send the following headers

**Custom Header Name**: X-UA-Compatible 
 
**Custom Header Value**: IE=EmulateIE7

that supposed to force IE 8 into IE 7 Compatibility mode.  You can read more about it on [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc288325(VS.85).aspx) .

I have noticed by looking in the Developer toolbar that if I have a DTD defined the document mode correctly gets set to IE 7, but the browser mode is IE 8.  If the page doesn't have a DTD the document mode gets set to Quirks and Browser Mode once again IE 8.

Am I doing something wrong.  How do I force IE 8 to set IE 7 Browser mode.

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Browser Mode refers to the user-agent header sent by the browser.  Since the UA has already been sent before the HTTP response comes back containing your EmulateIE7 directive, it's too late to change the browser mode; only the document mode is changed.

See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd565628(VS.85).aspx#bdmodes

Answer (score 6):

I've used this meta tag to force the IE7 mode:

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=EmulateIE7" />
```

Important: you must put this before any other tags in `<head>`!

(actually you might be able to put a `<title>` before this, but not putting anything is easier to remember than the specific cases)

Comment: The IIS setting that the OP is using adds this header automatically, so you don't need to include the meta tag in the pages.

Comment: Note that you can overwrite the IIS setting with the meta tag as well.

Comment: I know it's an old post, but your note that this tag has to be the first tag in the `<head>` section saved me! Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Check this link

http://ilia.ws/archives/196-IE8-X-UA-Compatible-Rant.html

Need to add a custom header as described in the link.  Still looking for a non header solution when using the transitional DTD.

Comment: additional link http://www.terminally-incoherent.com/blog/2009/07/27/forcing-ie8-compatibility-mode-in-iis/

Answer (score 0):

I think that's working as designed.  I've been using that header value with no problems.

Are you having rendering issues on your pages?  You could try using IE=IE7 instead.

Answer (score 0):

found this solution... hope it works!

Notice:  You will have to put the "header" line before any html is sent to the browser (http://www.php.net/header)

It's PHP code, the line should be like this:

header('X-UA-Compatible: IE=7');

Answer (score 0):

If you followed that guide too closely you will miss the fact that the web.config way of fixing this is only supported in IIS 7 +.

Via [MSDN] article link in OP

> Configuring Web Servers to Specify
>   Default Compatibility Modes
>
> Site administrators can configure
>   their sites to default to a specific
>   document compatibility mode by
>   defining a custom header for the site.
>   The specific process depends on your
>   Web server. For example, the following
>   web.config file enables Microsoft
>   Internet Information Services (IIS) to
>   define a custom header that
>   automatically renders all pages in IE7
>   mode.

BUT see: [IIS.NET article](http://www.iis.net/ConfigReference/system.webServer/httpProtocol/customHeaders/)

```
IIS 7.0  The <customHeaders> element of the <httpProtocol> element was introduced in IIS 7.0.
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    <!-- Use IE7 mode added on 13th October for IE8 BSCI-->
           <!--  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=EmulateIE7" /> -->
    <!-- Use IE7 mode added on 20th October for IE8 BSCI-->
            <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=IE7" /> <!--- This appears to work on testing! -->    
            <!-- END -->
```

Using 'Emulate' did not work but IE=IE7 did